# When I compile my program, why does it complain with "label at end of compound statement"?

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement

When I try to compile my code, I keep getting this error message:

```
badges.c: In function ‘badgeAnyColor’:
badges.c:335: error: label at end of compound statement
```

To help you see where it is complaining about, the complaints are on the last line of the switch statement, it says: "case 5: ". And one more concern I have is whether or not I'm doing the switch statement correctly syntax wise (I'm completely new to using switch statements with if/else statements) Help would be appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
int badgeAnyColor(int x, int y) {
       int bronzebadges, northbadges, northeastbadges, northwestbadges, eastbadges,
          westbadges, southbadges, southeastbadges, southwestbadges, polybadge;
    
       double fs, ht, fp, sunexp, irrexp;
    
       if ((x >= 1 && x <= 20) && (y >= 1 && y <= 20)) {
          fs = fieldScore(x, y);
          ht = harvestTime(x, y);
          fp = fieldProfit(x, y);
          sunexp = sunExposure(x, y);
          irrexp = irrigationExposure(x, y);
          bronzebadges = countBadges(x, y);
          northbadges = countBadges(x, y + 1);
          northeastbadges = countBadges(x + 1, y + 1);
          northwestbadges = countBadges(x - 1, y + 1);
          eastbadges = countBadges(x + 1, y);
          westbadges = countBadges(x - 1, y);
          southbadges = countBadges(x - 1, y - 1);
          southeastbadges = countBadges(x + 1, y - 1);
          southwestbadges = countBadges(x - 1, y - 1);
    
          switch (bronzebadges) {
             case 0: {
                if (x == 1 && y == 1) {
                   if (northbadges == 0 && northeastbadges == 0 &&
                      eastbadges == 0) {
                      polybadge = 1;
                   }
                   else {
                      polybadge = 0;
                   }
                }
                if (x == 20 && y == 1) {
                   if (northbadges == 0 && northwestbadges == 0 &&
                      westbadges == 0) {
                      polybadge = 1;
                   }
                   else {
                      polybadge = 0;
                   }
                }
                if (x == 1 && y == 20) {
                   if (eastbadges == 0 && southeastbadges == 0 &&
                      southbadges == 0) {
                      polybadge = 1;
                   }
                   else {
                      polybadge = 0;
                   }
                }
                if (x == 20 && y == 20) {
                   if (westbadges == 0 && southwestbadges == 0 &&
                      southbadges == 0) {
                      polybadge = 1;
                   }
                   else {
                      polybadge = 0;
                   }
                }
                if ((x >= 2 && x <= 19) && y == 1) {
                   if (westbadges == 0 && northwestbadges == 0 && northbadges == 0
                      && northeastbadges == 0 && eastbadges == 0) {
                      polybadge = 1;
                   }
                   else {
                      polybadge = 0;
                   }
                }
                return polybadge;
             }
             case 1: {
                if (fs >= 20) {
                   polybadge = 1;
                }
                else {
                   polybadge = 0;
                }
                return polybadge;
             }
             case 2: {
                if (fp <= 0 || ht < 80 || sunexp > irrexp) {
                   polybadge = 1;
                }
                else {
                   polybadge = 0;
                }
                return polybadge;
             }
             case 3: {
                if ((x >= 2 && x <= 19) && y == 1) {
                   if (((westbadges + northbadges) >= 2) || ((northbadges +
                      eastbadges) >= 2) || ((westbadges + eastbadges) >= 2)) {
                      polybadge = 1;
                   }
                   else {
                      polybadge = 0;
                   }
                }
                if (x == 1 && y == 1) {
                   if ((northbadges + eastbadges) >= 2) {
                      polybadge = 1;
                   }
                   else {
                      polybadge = 0;
                   }
                }
                if (x == 20 && y == 1) {
                   if ((northbadges + westbadges) >= 2) {
                      polybadge = 1;
                   }
                   else {
                      polybadge = 0;
                   }
                }
                if (x == 1 && y == 20) {
                   if ((southbadges + eastbadges) >= 2) {
                      polybadge = 1;
                   }
                   else {
                      polybadge = 0;
                   }
                }
                if (x == 20 && y == 20) {
                   if ((southbadges + westbadges) >= 2) {
                      polybadge = 1;
                   }
                   else {
                      polybadge = 0;
                   }
                }
                if ((x >= 2 && x <= 19) && y == 20) {
                   if (((westbadges + southbadges) >= 2) || ((southbadges +
                      eastbadges) >= 2) || ((westbadges + eastbadges) >= 2)) {
                      polybadge = 1;
                   }
                   else {
                      polybadge = 0;
                   }
                }
                else {
                   if (((northbadges + westbadges) >= 2) || ((westbadges +
                      southbadges) >= 2) || ((southbadges + eastbadges) >= 2) ||
                         ((northbadges + southbadges) >= 2) || ((westbadges +
                            eastbadges) >= 2)) {
                      polybadge = 1;
                   }
                   else {
                      polybadge = 0;
                   }
                }
                return polybadge;
             }
             case 4:
             case 5:
          }
       }
       else {
          polybadge = -1;
       }
       return polybadge;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> error: label at end of compound statement

The above error is because of these two cases

```
case 4:
case 5: 
    // here you need to add statement 
    //if you don't want to do anything simple break statement will work for you
    break;
```

Right now You are not using these two cases You can also remove them.

> What if I want the same thing that happened in case 3 to also happen in case 4 and 5?? And thanks for the input

You need to move case 4, and case 5

```
case 3:
case 4:
case 5: 
//statements you written for case 3
```

For example

```
switch(n)
{
    case 1:  
        printf("case 1");
        break;
    case 2:  
        printf("case 2");
        break;
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5: 
        printf("case 3 or 4 or 5");
        break;
    default: 
        printf("Wrong choice");
        break;

}
```

Comment: Except I'd indent that `break`.

Comment: @aragaer - `break` must be explicit in C, otherwise execution goes on to the following case. This is true for your other cases as well.

Comment: @mouviciel Of course. Nevertheless, indenting it properly is not bad.

Answer (score 4):

A `switch` in C consists of a set of case labels that must contain statements. Loosely speaking, a statement is something that terminates with a `;`. Code like

```
switch (n){
    case 4:
    case 5:
}
```

is invalid since there is no statement to execute. **That is what is giving you a compile error.** One fix is to write

```
switch (n){
    case 4:
    case 5:
        ;
}
```

where `;` is denotes an empty statement. Note that switches in `C` have the follow-through feature meaning that `case4` runs into `case5`. That's why you don't need an empty statement just after `case4`.

Better still, just remove those cases.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify what is supposed to happen for case 5 (and case 4); right now there's nothing, and that's what it's complaining about - you gave it a case label, but didn't tell it what to do for that case.

If you don't want anything to happen, you can just leave the cases out of your switch.

Comment: What if I want the same thing that happened in case 3 to also happen in case 4 and 5?? And thanks for the input!

Comment: @karen: That would be `case 3: case 4: case 5: ..(your code)`. Is `polybadge` only used to temporarily store the return value? It seems to me you can replace each line `polybadge = X;` immediately with `return X`. It should also make all of those `if..else` a bit easier to read.

Comment: Hmm, I want to return the correct value of polybadge when a user inputs a field (x, y). So those if..else statements are specifying the intervals/conditions that each case has to meet in order to earn a badge. So yes, polybadge does store the return value! :) Oh so, instead of putting the code in case 3, I would put it in case 5?

Answer (score 1):

Label at end of compound statement is the `case 5:` without anything to execute. What you need is at least `break`:

```
case 4:
case 5:
    // do nothing
    break;
```

Now about syntax - it does seem wrong. First - you don't need extra brackets for code in case. Second - you DO need `break` in the end of each block unless you want to "fall-through" to next case branch. If you do want, add a comment stating stating so:

```
case 1:
    do_something();
    break;
case 2:
    do_something_else();
    /* fall-through */
case 3:
    and_something_else_more();
    break;
case 42:
    if (allow_easter_eggs) // like this
        printf("DON'T PANIC\n");
    break;
```

This will perform `do_something()` in case of 1, `do_something_else()` and `and_something_else_more()` in case of 2, and just `and_something_else_more()` for 3.

Finally it's always a good idea to add a `default` label too.

Comment: Ah okay thanks. So if I were to use if/else statements within a switch statement, how would that generally look??